# Unique identifier of a video file

Tags: python, file, operating-system, filesystems

Use case:
I have a youtube playlist.
I want to sync this playlist to my local computer.

```
Algorithm:
for each video in playlist:
  if not exist an file name video["videoID"].mp4 in directory "C:\Users\username\Desktop":
    download the video name video["videoID"].mp4 in directory "C:\Users\username\Desktop"
```

but it seems name is not a very good identifier. Reason 1: filename could be changed accidentally.   Reason 2: some video ID have special character not accepted as file name in window10.

Is there any identifier of a video file that is guarantee not  to change once initialized or once created？

Answer (score 1):

There is no such identifier by default.
You could either use a hash of the file, which might slow down the validation by a lot if you have many large files, or you could set custom metadata for the videos(e.g. using ffmpeg) and keep a database for which uuids translate to which urls.